# page metadata of PaginationModel is showing undefined in mui data grid

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I am making a project using nextjs and MUI data grid. I need to achieve Server Side Pagination in DataGrid but the pagination page metadata is showing undefined on function callback.

I am using styled DataGrid:

```
            rows={data}
            columns={columns}
            rowCount={pageCount}
            paginationModel={paginationModel}
            onPaginationModelChange={setPaginationModel}
            pageSizeOptions={[5]}
            paginationMode="server"
            rowModesModel="server"
            checkboxSelection
            disableRowSelectionOnClick
         />
```

```
const [paginationModel, setPaginationModel] = useState({ 
 //this is the metadata
      page: 0,
      pageSize: 5,
      currentPage: 1,
   })
   useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
         try {
            const response = await AllData(
               {
//this is the page but on second iteration it is showing undefined
                  page: paginationModel.currentPage,  
                  size: paginationModel.pageSize,
               },
               props.type
            )
            setPageCount(response.data.data.count)
            setData(response.data.data.rows)
         } catch (err) {
            toast.error(err)
         }
      }

      fetchData()
   }, [
      props.isTableRefreshed,
      paginationModel.currentPage,
      paginationModel.pageSize,
   ])
```